# Group rows and calculate mean and count

Tags: python, pandas

This is my data frame:

```
df = 
UD   QTY   GRADE   TIME_1   TIME_2
1    20    5       22.5     16.1
1    20    5       26.2     19.5
1    20    5       30.0     14.0
1    20    4       20.0     18.5
2    25    4       23.3     19.9
```

I need to calculate mean values of `TIME_1` and `TIME_2` per each combination of `UD`, and `QTY`. Then I want to add the new column `GRADE_COUNT` that will store the total count of rows per group. For instance, in the above-given data set there are 4 rows per group defined by `UD` = 1 and `QTY` = 20.

The result should be this one:

```
df = 

UD  QTY  MEAN_TIME_1   MEAN_TIME_2   COUNT
1   20   24.67         17.02         4
2   25   23.3          19.9          1
```

I wrote this code which groups rows, calculates mean values and counts values.

```
groupby_object = df[['UD', 'QTY', 'GRADE', 'TIME_1', 'TIME_2']].groupby(['TIME_1', 'TIME_2])

df = groupby_object.agg('mean').rename(columns = lambda x: x + ' mean').join(pd.DataFrame(groupby_object.size(),columns=['counts'])).reset_index()
```

But instead of calculating mean times, it calculates mean `QTY` and `GRADE`, also the column `UD` disappears.

Comment: `df.groupby(['UD','QTY'])[['TIME_1','TIME_2']].mean()` - is that what you want?

Comment: @MaxU: Please see my update. I posted the expected result.

Comment: @DavidZ: I am using the last version of pandas: 0.19.1

Comment: @MaxU: Thanks. But it will create two columns `count`: one per `TIME_1` and another per `TIME_2`. I need the total count of rows per group.

Comment: @Dinosaurius (3 comments up) Sorry, that was actually my mistake. Anyway, do you want to group by `GRADE` or not? You say both in your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's possible to do all different kind of aggregations in the same step without merging or assigning. `groupby.agg` allows you to do this with a dictionary of columns mapped to the aggregation function used

```
df1 = df.groupby(['UD', 'QTY']).agg({'TIME_1': 'mean', 
                                     'TIME_2': 'mean', 
                                     'GRADE':'count'}).reset_index()

   UD  QTY  TIME_1  GRADE  TIME_2
0   1   20  24.675      4  17.025
1   2   25  23.300      1  19.900
```

Comment: Could the final solution contain only rows that I specified as the expected result in my question?

Comment: It looks like you are only grouping by UD and QTY and not GRADE. Your final dataframe does not match what you wrote

Comment: yeah, this solution is MUCH better compared to mine

Answer (score 1):

The argument to `DataFrame.groupby()` specifies which columns should be used to combine rows into groups. So if you write

```
df.groupby([['TIME_1', 'TIME_2']])
```

then Pandas will combine rows which have the same values of `TIME_1` and `TIME_2`. But you want to combine rows which have the same values of `UD` and `QTY`. (If you also want to use `GRADE` to group rows, just add that in where appropriate.) So use

```
>>> g = df.groupby([['UD', 'QTY']])
```

Then you can just call `mean()` on the resulting object to get the means of the groups.

```
>>> g.mean()
        GRADE  TIME_1  TIME_2
UD QTY                       
1  20    4.75  24.675  17.025
2  25    4.00  23.300  19.900
```

Similarly, you can call `count()` to get row counts.

```
>>> g.count()
        GRADE  TIME_1  TIME_2
UD QTY                       
1  20       4       4       4
2  25       1       1       1
```

You can now assemble these pieces into a new `DataFrame` using `pandas.concat()`.

```
>>> m = g.mean()
>>> c = g.count()
>>> new_df = concat([m, c], axis=1)
>>> new_df
        TIME_1  TIME_2  GRADE
UD QTY                       
1  20   24.675  17.025      4
2  25   23.300  19.900      1
```

All that remains is to change `UD` and `QTY` from index columns to regular columns, which you can do with `new_df.reset_index()`, and change the column names to your liking, which you can do by assigning a list to `new_df.columns`.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
In [295]: g = df.groupby(['UD','QTY'], as_index=False)

In [297]: (pd.merge(g[['TIME_1','TIME_2']].mean(),
     ...:           g.size().to_frame('COUNT').reset_index(),
     ...:           on=['UD','QTY'])
     ...: )
     ...:
Out[297]:
   UD  QTY  TIME_1  TIME_2  COUNT
0   1   20  24.675  17.025      4
1   2   25  23.300  19.900      1
```

or a bit nicer one:

```
In [301]: g[['TIME_1','TIME_2']].mean().assign(COUNT=g.size().values)
Out[301]:
   UD  QTY  TIME_1  TIME_2  COUNT
0   1   20  24.675  17.025      4
1   2   25  23.300  19.900      1
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly that if, for instance, I do not need to calculate mean times, then I should simply run `g.assign(COUNT=g[['TIME_1','TIME_2']].size().values)` excluding `[['TIME_1','TIME_2']].mean()` ?

Comment: @Dinosaurius, i would try this: `g.size().to_frame('COUNT').reset_index()`

Comment: @Dinosaurius, you should probably mark [Ted's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41474022/5741205) as a correct one - it's much better and more idiomatic